# $.jqx.dataAdapter is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

The data is not being displayed. I tried debugging the cide in the degugger. I get an error `$.jqx.dataAdapter is not a constructor` The data is successfully populated in the `aDataSet`. Please tell me what could possible be wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aDataSet = [
                //loading data --successful    

  ];

  var source =
        {
            localdata: aDataSet,
            datatype: "array",
            dataFields:
            [   
                { name: 'empcode', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'srno', type:'number'},
                { name: 'projectcode', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'projectname', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'startdate', type: 'date' },
                { name: 'enddate', type: 'date' },
                { name: 'clientname', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'modify', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'delete', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'view', type: 'string' }
            ]                     
        };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter( this.source ,{
    loadComplete: function (aDataSet) { },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { }      
  });
  // create jqxDataTable.
 $("#tableid").jqxDataTable(
 {
    source: dataAdapter,
    pageable: true,
    altRows: true,
    filterable: true,
    height: 400,
    filterMode: 'advanced',
    width: 850,
    columns: [

       { text: 'Sr No', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'srno', width: 200 },
       { text: 'Emp Code', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'empcode', width: 200 },
       { text: 'Project Code', dataField: 'Quantity', cellsformat: 'd', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', width: 100 },
       { text: 'Project Name', dataField: 'Price', cellsformat: 'c2', align: 'center', cellsAlign: 'center', width: 70 },
       { text: 'Start Date', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'startdate', width: 100 },
       { text: 'End Date', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'enddate',width: 100 },
       { text: 'Client Name', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'enddate',width: 100 },
       { text: 'Status', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'status',width: 100 },
       { text: 'Modify', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'modify',width: 100 },
       { text: 'Delete', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'delete',width: 100 },
       { text: 'View', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'view',width: 100 }
     ]
  });
 });
```

Comment: I am calling the function with this: `<div id="tableid" >`
    </div>

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you show your HTML, not only your JS, so we can see if you had the same problem or not. I had the same problem and the solution was to add the reference to jqxdata, as it is explained here:

https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/b-jqx-dataadapter-is-not-a-constructor/

For example, i was trying to add a jqx-data-table into a website. Originally I had this in my references (Jquery and other references are in other place):

```
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
```

So i just added, at the beggining, this one:

```
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
```

Result:

```
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I got it resolved earlier. Turns out that we had the same problem. JqxData.js was missing. So I added it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a publicly accessible link for debugger. That would attract more people...